# Why did I receive 4.000.000 $ for free?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

So, I just logged in, and when I joined the lobby, I received an alert with the message `Congratulations, you have been awarded 4000000$`. I have no idea why or how, I didn't do any specific events. The only thing which "happened" was that I have 400 hours on GTA V on steam since yesterday.

Could that be the reason? Or is there some kind of event I missed? Or could this be done by a hacker?

Comment: Did you buy any shark card?

Comment: @Alex I received a 8 million $ shark card from my brother for christmas. Bit early tho, but I already received that money. So why would I get another 4 million? I didn't buy any shark cards earlier except one for 250k in the beginning.

Comment: @Alex Alright nice, I'll accept it in 7 min. ;D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the money as a "gift" for buying shark cards. The more you buy, the more they give you for free as an extra.

Comment: Yesterday I've been "Congratulations, you've been awarded 250,000" and I never bought any shark card.